# JSON Schema - Foreign Key (FK) Validation

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have the JSON schemas below:

**Schema A:**

```js
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/hyper-schema#",
  "title": "A",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "entityBId": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "name",
    "entityBId"
  ],
  "links": [
    {
      "rel": "B",
      "href": "myapi/EntityB?id={entityBId}"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Schema B** :

```js
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "B",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "name"
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to run something like a integrity check based in a JSON Schema with external links/references.
For instance: When I receive an Object A with a **entityBId** = 1, I'd like to fetch this entity B running a GET in the endpoint declared in the links href and check if there is a valid object from the received id.
It will run like a deep validation and can be useful in a scenario without a defined DB schema.

Comment: nope, json is not xml.
if you wish to validate, then you have to define a function -- to do the validations -- and call that function in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Raj Kamal, I made my own "link validation".
There is a function that looks for link attribute on schemas and validate the externals references directly on database and throw an exception if a valid reference is not found.